# When a question pertains to specifically configuring an editor, shouldn't it be migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, migration

It is common to gain a lot of reputation from really simple & basic questions about Visual Studio code. The highest scoring answer on my account is about configuring the color of brackets in VS Code.

Now, in all fairness, some of the questions have to do with TextMate grammars, certain fields in JSON files with a schema that defines them (like VS Code Theme development) etc... But some questions are like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310734/how-to-add-more-indentation-in-the-visual-studio-code-explorer-file-tree-structu/55315106#55315106) (which I randomly picked from some of the highest scoring settings). That question asks about adding indentation to a file tree. I don't understand how that pertains to coding.

I get that the editor is a piece of software used as a tool to code, but it seems like some of the questions don't really belong on Stack Overflow. I could totally be wrong, I am hoping to create a less blurred line, which is a metaphor that I think properly describes the topic. "A line, that is blurred, between programming, and configuring software".

I never see VS code questions closed due to *"not being appropriate for this site"*, and I am really active on that tag. Yet, I frequently see other editors have questions closed for that reason, and I would like to know why that it is. I was hoping someone who can describe this topic with more prudence than I can, would enlighten me.

Comment: The description for the close reason used to be better. The things that determines whether or not the post is off topic isn't whether or not the _action_ pertains to coding, but whether or not the _software_ is primarily used for software development. Read: VS Code questions are on topic as they're about a tool which is designed for programming, even if the question isn't specifically programming related. Questions about Notepad are off topic as while you can code in Notepad, it's not a tool developed for programming.

Comment: This guy seemed to think questions about IDEs were on-topic (but what does he know @JoelSpolsky ) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904986/836330

Comment: @Mark in 2009 there were only 1 site, heck, if you go that back you will find straight up [off topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35709/792066)

Comment: @Braiam one doesn't need to go back in time to find straight up off topic questions.

Comment: @Braiam Super User goes back to 2008.  You should look at some of Jeff Atwood's posts there and on SO concerning Visual Studio.  Very interesting.

Comment: People get really defensive over certain topics. A few of the people who are commenting should know how much I answer questions about VS Code (I Love the editor, absolutely love it, I would pay for it  no questions asked) this wasn't trying to shoot down IDEs, there was a question closed that asked about some little simple thing that pertained  to an IDE. I initiated a close vote due to it being of topic. I felt installing an IDE was a question that belonged on Super User. Another higher rep user disagreed with me, so I flagged my own question and let the moderater decide.

Comment: The moderator left the question closed with the initial reaso I voted to close it. But I couldn't help to think, maybe the questions I have been answering don't really belong on stack overflow. Sometimes, to me, it seems like reputation thats gained too easy, as I personally know developers (being a CS major) that really can't write code, but they can write a VS Code theme. (This is where i get acussed of complaining). The question isn't a complaint, its a debate, and I feel it should be asked about and discussed. The debate defines the very essence of stack overflows purpose IMO.

Comment: It hits dead on the fundamental question, a question that we should all ask, a question that becomes more important as you keep gaining those silver yearling badges. What actual value is there in Stack Overflow Reputation? And what does it mean to be a reputable stack overflow user?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No.** Editors and IDEs fall into the category of software tools commonly used by programmers engaged in the work of software development, so they are on-topic for Stack Overflow, per [the Help Center's "on-topic" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Such questions may *also* be on-topic for Super User, Vim, Emacs, and other Stack Exchange sites, but that is not a reason to close them on and/or migrate them from Stack Overflow. Questions are never migrated unless they are off-topic on the site where they are asked.

Unfortunately, there exists a *lot* of misunderstanding about what is on-topic on Stack Overflow, both on the sides of askers and close-voters. So, plenty of off-topic questions do get asked here, and plenty of questions that are actually on-topic here do end up getting erroneously closed. Therefore, you can't judge our topicality standards empirically—you need to look at the rules set out in the Help Center.

Regarding your complaint about "simple and basic questions", there's nothing wrong with asking simple and basic questions on Stack Overflow. We have no requirements along those lines. In fact, [our goal](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is to build a library of high-quality answers to every question about programming. Simple and basic questions fall into this category, and, as you can see by views and voting, these are often the most *useful* questions in the long run to researchers. Everyone is a beginner at something, so what seems simple and basic to a knowledgeable person is often neither to someone who doesn't know—at least, until they find the answer!

(Disclaimer: Sometimes—even often—simple and basic questions are duplicates of questions that have already been asked, due to their obviousness. While it's natural for new developers to want to ask these questions, asking questions which have already been asked and answered here is something that is discouraged and can usually be avoided by doing sufficient prior research. The problem with these questions is not that they are simple or basic, but rather that they are duplicates of questions already asked on Stack Overflow, and there is a way built into the system to handle that.)

Comment: I'll upvote this, but only because this is about an IDE which is used pretty much ONLY for programming tasks/problems. This answer, in my opinion, does not 100% apply to all tools that may be commonly used by programmers. You can even argue that a question like "How to add a font to the IDE" is not a programming question, but a high degree of flexibility is required to not constantly have to bicker about what goes in and what does not. I just don't want to constantly see questions about IDEs being discussed on meta, just let them all in and let's not pucker too much.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, isn't that what I said? Questions about IDEs and editors used by programmers are on-topic. Full stop.

Comment: @Gimby and I will downvote it for the same reason. I'm not a carpenter because I have a hammer and a saw. The same way I'm not a programmer because I have an IDE. The tools doesn't make me a professional, the task does.

Comment: @CodyGray The OP to this question edited the tags on the question linked to within his question, to remove the `vscode-settings` tag which is highly relevant.  I am unable to edit the tags to fix that.  Is there some process that prevents that for some time?

Comment: I continue to believe firmly that Stack Overflow made a **serious** error in judgment by deciding that such questions should be on topic. I wouldn't go to chess.se for tech support for an online chess website (they take questions about rating scales, but that's about it), or to music.se to find out how to set the BPM on my new digital metronome, or cooking.se because I need to know where to order a replacement part for my air fryer. These kinds of questions are why a) documentation and b) specialized support forums exist.

Comment: SO is full of people who use these tools every day, it's easily the most applicable place for questions about them.

Comment: @CodyGray Gray I don't know if its fair to call it a complaint. If I have a complaint you'll get an email, as that is the proper channel for complaints IMO, not a post on meta. Also If you look at who is answering questions in VS Code, I have been one of the major contributors over the last year. I am asking because I don't feel its as clear in the help forums as you say it is. Or maybe it is, but I havn't seen the documentation on it. To be honest I would like to know a lot more about how you, as a moderator, decide what should be, and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @CodyGray (continued) ...And how I can help (accurately) to make sure that I am voting to close the right answers, and so I can say somthing when I see a question closed for the wrong reason. Also, because it seems to be the case that IDE questions are allowed on SO, I asked a moderator to review a question that I incorrectly closed for not pertaining to this site (it was an IDE Q), I asked them to change the reason for the question being closed, and they rejected it, w/o comment, so it seems they agreed with the original reason, which is very confusing, considering the response I got 2 this Q

Comment: @jD3V I don't know what you're talking about. If you had a complaint about Stack Overflow or its moderation, you wouldn't send an email; you'd post on Meta. I don't know why I would look at who is primarily answering questions about VS Code. That has nothing to do with whether the questions are on-topic. To find out what's on-topic, I'd look in the Help Center's page that describes what is on-topic. It is quite clear here, and has been clear since the site was established some 15 years ago.

Comment: Moderators generally do not bother with changing close reasons from one to another. It isn't worth the time/effort. Again, I don't know what you're referring to. Maybe the flag you raised on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72611381), but that *did* get a response from a moderator (contrary to your claim that it was rejected without a comment). They said: "Closed is closed. Don't really need to involve mods for this. If the reason doesn't match, add a custom comment under the question."